# Is there a better way to write this? [jQuery - Best Practices - if statement]

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm working in SharePoint 2013 (for reference) and I have some (.aspx) pages with  titles.

I'm running a script that essentially checks the title of the page I'm on and if it matches any of my query titles, then it appends the blank href="variable-link"  with a page related URL.

(ie: if the page name contains the word "home" then make this "more info" link go to http://home-info.aspx)

I have this working in the following code. I was wondering if there was a better, more efficient way to write this.

```
/* Attach HREF to appropriate Function Page Events */

    if($("#pageTitle > span:contains('Americas')").length > 0) {
        $("a.events-link").attr("href", 'Americas-Events.aspx');          
    }
    if($("#pageTitle > span:contains('APAC')").length > 0) {
        $("a.events-link").attr("href", 'APAC-Events.aspx');          
    }
    if($("#pageTitle > span:contains('EMEA')").length > 0) {
        $("a.events-link").attr("href", 'EMEA-Events.aspx');          
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps change to `else if` to save some evaluation once you've found a match assuming you only expect one condition to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd use an array to put the text strings in, then loop with a `$.each`. When it's find a match, it will interrupt the loop using `return false`.

```
var options = ['Americas','APAC','EMEA'];

$.each(options, function() {

    var that = this.toString(),
    present = $('#pageTitle span:contains(' + that + ')');

    if (present.length) {
    $('a.events-link').attr('href', that + '-Events.aspx');
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY and cleaned up my wall-of-text.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to contribute. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would be more efficient to only search for that element once.

```
$("a.events-link").attr("href", function(i, href){
   // get text from title element and don't have to search dom for it again
   var pageTitle = $('#pageTitle > span').text();
   // text comparison/href value setting
   if( pagetTitle.indexOf('Americas') >-1){
      href = 'Americas-Events.aspx';
   }else if( pagetTitle.indexOf('APAC') >-1){
      href = 'APAC-Events.aspx';
   }else if( pagetTitle.indexOf('EMEA') >-1){
      href = 'EMEA-Events.aspx';
   }
   // will return original href if no other matches
   return href;
});
```

Above uses a slightly different method `attr(function)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it is best way or not but you can do something like this:

```
var href="";
if($("#pageTitle > span:contains('Americas')").length > 0) {
         href='Americas-Events.aspx';       
    }else if($("#pageTitle > span:contains('APAC')").length > 0) {
       href='APAC-Events.aspx';          
    }else if($("#pageTitle > span:contains('EMEA')").length > 0) {
        href='EMEA-Events.aspx';          
    }

  $("a.events-link").attr("href", href);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var href;
var span = $("#pageTitle > span").text();
switch (span) {
    case ('Americas'):
        href= 'Americas-Events.aspx';

        break;
    case ('APAC'):
        href= 'APAC-Events.aspx';

        break;
    case ('EMEA'):
        href= 'EMEA-Events.aspx';

        break;
$("a.events-link").attr("href", href);
```

This is another solution using switch.
I wont tell you its the best but its a possible solution.